# How do I unlock a concourse pool resource?

Tags: concourse

We are trying to use a concourse pool to get locking. It locks just fine but when we try to release the lock, we are getting this error `error releasing lock: open /tmp/build/put/maleficent-env/name: no such file or directory`.

This is what the directory tree in our pool repo looks like

```
.
├── README.md
└── maleficent
    ├── claimed
    │   └── maleficent-env
    └── unclaimed
```

this is our resource:

```
 - name: 1.12-env
   type: pool
   source:
     uri: git@github.com:<repo>
     branch: master
     pool: maleficent
     private_key: {{key}}
```

this acquires the lock:

`- put: 1.12-env
       params: {acquire: true}`

and this is the job yml we think should release it:

```
- name: run-1.12-errand
plan:
- aggregate:
  - get: 1.12-env
    passed: [the-job-that-got-the-lock]
  - get: ci
  on_failure:
    put: 1.12-env
    params: {release: maleficent-env}
- task: run-errand
  file: ci/run-errand/task.yml
  params:
    BOSH_DIRECTOR_URL: {{url}}
    BOSH_CLIENT_SECRET: {{secret}}
    ENV_NAME: maleficent
  ensure:
    put: 1.12-env
    params: {release: maleficent-env}
```

One thing we noticed was when we did the get for the resource, it seems to be `Cloning into '/tmp/build/get'…` which is a different directory from where the unlocking step is looking for the file. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following job.yml will release your environment successfully

```
- name: run-1.12-errand
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: 1.12-env
      passed: [the-job-that-got-the-lock]
    - get: ci
    on_failure:
      put: 1.12-env
      params: {release: 1.12-env}
  - task: run-errand
    file: ci/run-errand/task.yml
    params:
      BOSH_DIRECTOR_URL: {{url}}
      BOSH_CLIENT_SECRET: {{secret}}
      ENV_NAME: maleficent
    ensure:
      put: 1.12-env
      params: {release: 1.12-env}
```

The relevant line

```
put: 1.12-env
params: {release: 1.12-env}
```

actually refers to two separate things, despite being both using `1.12-env`. The `put: 1.12-env` means "Do a `put` of the resource named `1.12-env`", while the `release: 1.12-env` means "Release the environment in the *file* that was the output of the `get: 1.12-env`"

This is hopefully clearer in the following example

```
- name: run-1.12-errand
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: my-environment
      resource: 1.12-env
      passed: [the-job-that-got-the-lock]
    - get: ci
    on_failure:
      put: 1.12-env
      params: {release: my-environment}
  - task: run-errand
    file: ci/run-errand/task.yml
    params:
      BOSH_DIRECTOR_URL: {{url}}
      BOSH_CLIENT_SECRET: {{secret}}
      ENV_NAME: maleficent
    ensure:
      put: 1.12-env
      params: {release: my-environment}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `release: maleficent-env` part.

`release` needs you to provide the path where your lock file is located on the container.

In your case try updating the release block to:

`ensure:
        put: 1.12-env
        params: {release: 1.12-env}`

Let me know if that works. If it doesn't work, you can try `fly hijack` to the put container and see what path the lock is located in. You would then provide that path as the `release` value.